# URL navigation in a single page website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I have a single pager website where each of the buttons takes you to a separate section following an animation. I've set up an example here: https://dev.dport.me.

Currently when you navigate to a page, the URL stays the same. For example, navigating to the About section does not append `#about` to the URL. I would like the site to work more like a normal site in respect to navigation.

What is the best way to go about making it such that:

1. Navigating to a "page" changes the URL. Following the example, either to `#about`, or even better, `/about`.
2. Navigating directly to a subpage works. Meaning that if I navigate to `https://dev.dport.me/about`, it takes me straight to the subpage.
3. The back button works. Currently if you navigate into a subpage, you must use the back button on the page. The browser's back button just leaves the whole site.

Is there some pre-existing javascript library that does what I'm looking for? Or am I going to have to gun it alone, [perhaps with something like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Comment: There are a number of different client side routing libraries. Also there are frameworks for single page apps like angular, vue, ember, react etc

Comment: I'd love to hear about them, given my situation which do you think is best? Perhaps I was just searching for the wrong thing on google...

Comment: Try a search for "javascript client router/routing" as well as look at some of the frameworks mentioned

Comment: this might do what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Grapnel looks promising. I want something lightweight because really this is just a static site with some fancy animations. I'm not looking to introduce node.js or frameworks or anything, just something I can drop into the index page's html.

Comment: Client side frameworks can be simple script tags and not require using node

Comment: Well I'm not having much luck with either Grapnel or page.js. They're just overwriting the button behaviour so the page doesn't navigate. So if anyone has a nice simple thing that I can just drop in that'd be great. Seems like a simple enough thing.

Comment: I ended up getting most of it with just coding it up manually with the various push and pop state functions. Thanks everyone!